# Make multiple parallel grpc unary api calls in python

Tags: python, grpc

I am trying to use some kind of parallelism in making multiple grpc calls in python in parallel.

Lets say I have a set of requests. For each such request, I want to make a grpc unary api call. How can I do this in parallel in python?

I read about asyncio. However, this is not applicable in the case of grpc calls. I need to wait on something that is asynchronous itself. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked into `my_stub.MyRPCMethod.future`? Affording arbitrarily many concurrent calls is what it's there to do.

Comment: @NathanielManistaAtGoogle But how scalable that is? I did a benchmarking and in a second, I could only see that 500 of the futures are finished and give a result. I am assuming it is internally using ThreadPoolExecutor as well. Any suggestions, what could have gone wrong?

Comment: It should be reasonably scalable; it's certainly not doing thread-per-RPC for control flow and I don't think it's using ThreadPoolExecutor. Are these secure RPCs? I think there may be some excessive use of threading in some of our credentials objects.

Comment: @NathanielManistaAtGoogle. This is what I am getting right now. I am wondering if I am benchmarking it the wrong way. Would really appreciate some suggestion